# Android Studio - Maps.me setup

Tags: android

I am trying to install the Maps.me api from https://github.com/mapswithme/api-android

From that site it says the file libs is a library Project. I followed this link to add a library project to Android Studio - http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/

Adding the lib went fine, I called the new module MapMe

When I did my Build, I get the following error. Found in the folder MapMe in the file build.gradle (this file was imported from libs)
MapsMe - build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {

  // Define these properties in the gradle.properties file in the root project folder
  compileSdkVersion propTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
  buildToolsVersion propBuildToolsVersion

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion propMinSdkVersion.toInteger()
    targetSdkVersion propTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
  }

  sourceSets.main {
    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    java.srcDirs = ['src']
    res.srcDirs = ['res']
  }
}
```

The error is Error:(6, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':MapMe'.
Could not find property 'propTargetSdkVersion' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@659c6fe1.

From my root directory, under Gradle Scrpts, I see a file gradle properties (Project Properties).

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Is the above file the one that I should add something to? If so, what would I add to it?

Thanks, John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace all `prop` versions to integers in your build.gradle of Maps.me. For example:

```
compileSdkVersion 17 
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
```

**Important:** Match all these versions with your original versions mentioned in your project build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Malwinder,

I think you are on the right track so I will give you the correct answer.

I actually got an answer back from the creator Dmitry Yunitsky.

Here is the correct gradle.properties (Project Properties)

```
    # Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
propMinSdkVersion=19
propTargetSdkVersion=22
propBuildToolsVersion=22.0.1
```

And you are correct, the values must match your build.gradle